The options 'driver' or 'driverClass' are mandatory if a connection URL without scheme is given to DriverManager::getConnection() exception Shopware 6
I migrated the Shopware 6 installation to the server and I'm getting following error
The options 'driver' or 'driverClass' are mandatory if a connection URL without scheme is given to DriverManager::getConnection(). Given URL: DATABASE_URL=mysql://xxx:xxx@localhost:3306/xxx
Can someone point me how to fix this issue?

You probably put single quotes around your DATABASE_URL variable. Check this by dumping the variable in src/Core/Framework/Adapter/Database/MySQLFactory.php:31
dd($url);

